# How to constantly confirm the status of a JMS consumer

Tags: java, jms

I have a Spring Boot microservice using the JMS API to consume messages from an ActiveMQ queue.

My current issue is that the microservice often loses its subscription as consumer. I'd like to create a logic to constantly check the status of the consumer and apply a retry strategy when lost.

Is there any way to confirm the status of a subscription as a consumer or to access the number of consumers per queue?

It's worth noting that the microservice serves as consumer and not a producer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're consuming the message synchronously (e.g. via [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive--)) and there is a problem with the connection then an exception should be thrown. When an exception is thrown you can implement your retry strategy as appropriate.

If you are consuming messages asynchronously (i.e. using a [`MessageListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html)) then you should set an [`ExceptionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html) on the [`javax.jms.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setExceptionListener-javax.jms.ExceptionListener-) to catch any exception and implement your retry strategy as appropriate.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the feedback; Yes I'm consuming asynchronously by using MessageListener and already catching ExceptionListener then any other Exception.
I'm not generating any exception once my app is loosing its subscription, so far what notifies me is an alert set on the queue end, that the num of consumers is 0. 

That's why I'd like to know if there is a way to confirm if that consumer it is still being subscribed, something like after a message is being consumed and processed.

Comment: If your client is losing its connection to the broker and an exception is never thrown then that's almost certainly a bug in the JMS client you're using. You should clarify your question with the fact that you're using `MessageListener` and `ExceptionListener` as well as details about the client you're using and its configuration.